Does the number of parameters in the model affect its intelligence?
I am trying to run a local AI with Ollama. I chose TinyLlama as the model. According to the documentation, TinyLlama accepts parameter 1.10B. I tried to ask something general but the result failed.
I chose another model, the orca-mini and asked the same question as before, the result was better.
So, does the number of parameters in the model affect its intelligence?
If yes, how to improve the result of the model with a small number of parameters?

"Intelligence" is a hard thing to quantify.
Measured as "performance on standard benchmarks", number of parameters strongly influences a model's performance.  For example, GPT-3's performance scales logarithmically with parameter count, where each doubling of the number of parameters results in an additional three points on the benchmark scores.  All LLMs appear to exhibit similar scaling properties, which is why the leading models are all datacenter-spanning behemoths.
However, parameter count is not the only factor.  Training can also have a strong influence.  On the LMSYS chatbot leaderboard, Llama 3 (70 billion parameters) is competitive with GPT-4-Turbo (believed to be 1.8 trillion parameters).  A likely explanation for this is that Llama 3 is far more densely trained: roughly 220 tokens of training data per parameter versus GPT-4's reported 7 tokens per parameter.


so does the number of parameters in the model affect its intelligence?

Yes, e.g. see the GPT-4 Technical Report:


how to improve the result of the model with a small number of parameters?

See:

MiniLLM: Knowledge Distillation of Large Language Models
Baby Llama
TinyLLM: Learning a Small Student from Multiple Large Language Models
MobileLLM: Optimizing Sub-billion Parameter Language Models for On-Device Use Cases
Phi-3 Technical Report: A Highly Capable Language Model Locally on Your Phone
https://huggingface.co/blog/smollm: "state-of-the-art small models with 135M, 360M, and 1.7B parameters, trained on a new high-quality dataset".

